# java.lang.NullPointerException (MVC pattern)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller

I'm trying to build a Java EE web application using the MVC pattern. So I implemented two packages dao and service.

and in my service class methods, I call the dao package methods.

So when running a Test class, using the methods from the service package I get the java.lang.NullPointerException, and everything works fine when using the dao package.

in service package :

```
private ProjectDao projectDao;    
public void deleteProject(Long id) {
            projectDao.deleteProject(id);

        }
```

in dao package :

```
public void deleteProject(Long id) {

        Project p = projectById(id);

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(p);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();

    }
```

Comment: Can you add the part of the stacktrace that shows the NPE? Would also be nice to know the line (in the code above) that causes the NPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your delete Project Method is no class method you need to instantiate your object before using its methods. (Also maybe your compiler warned you that your variable might not have been instantiated)

EDIT: Also: did you import your package?

Comment: Yes I had to instantiate the projectDao object. Now it's working fine.